# How to add values in a "Set" included in a "Map"?

Tags: java, collections

I have the collection:

```
private Map<Integer,Set<Meal>> storage = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

I have "save" method for adding new objects

```
public void save(Meal meal)
```

The logic I need is to add this meal into the SET using merge() or computeIfAbsent() method.
For example - when I'm trying to add new Meal I should get some key from the Meal(a private field with a getter), and the Meal should be added to the Set of this pair.
How it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

first `computeIfAbsent` (thus it is guaranteed that your set is never null), 
then immediately `add`

```
    class Meal {
        final int key;

        Meal(int key) {
            this.key = key;
        }
    }

    Map<Integer, Set<Meal>> storage = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    Consumer<Meal> save = (meal) -> storage
            .computeIfAbsent(meal.key, (Integer key) -> new HashSet<>())
            .add(meal);
```